# To make a lengthy process instantaneous

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What is a word that describes the process of speeding up a lengthy process, so that it can be described as instantaneous? In a sense of *to remove any delay*.

*Instantiate* comes to mind, but it is also a programming term, which may sound confusing. Is it the correct word, though? If not, what is?

Example: "The reaction takes 4 seconds to complete, but I bet we can *make it instant*".

What verb can be used to turn "*make it instant*" into "*(verb) it*"?

Comment: Optimizing? Accelerating? Polaroid Instamatic?

Comment: An example of what you are describing would be more than a little helpful.

Comment: +1 to optimize, although you can optimize something wrt other dimensions than time.

Comment: There is _instantize_ also but it is mainly used in food industry.

Comment: `Instantiate` definitely does not mean to speed up a lengthy process. It is indeed a programming term, meaning to make an instance of. To `instantiate a class` is to `make an instance of a class`, aka an object.

Comment: By the way, theoretically, chemical reactions cannot be instantaneous: "Chemists have identified the existence of a barrier to **instant reaction**. By making measurements on the effect of temperature on the rates of reactions, they have identified the need for molecules to acquire at least a minimum energy, called the *activation energy*, before the atoms of the reactants are able to rearrange into products."  books.google.co.in/books?id=aLF6ZPQ222cC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=chemistry+"instant+reaction"

Comment: @Kris Yeah, I know, that's just an example. Definition of "instant" varies from process to process too.

Comment: *Instantiate* is not just used in programming; according to the OED, it was invented in 1946 as a technical term in philosophy, where it means essentially the same thing it does in programming: *"To represent by an instance."*

Answer (score 7):

*Expedite*, meaning "to make (an action or process) happen sooner or be accomplished more quickly."

> Amazon two-day shipping *expedites* product delivery.

Comment: +1 for expedite. The other two are not suitable for this, IMO, and the definitions you provide for them show why.  They are not really about removing all delay, but are more about triggering.  They can be parts of a solution that speeds up the overall process, however.

Comment: +1 for expedite, but I would vote down for the others, I suggest you remove them.

Comment: @ChrisSunami: Since the overwhelming majority seems opposed to both "precipitate" and "catalyze," I have decided to remove them from my answer.

Comment: Have you checked the dictionary? https://www.google.com/#q=define+%22expedite%22

Answer (score 1):

You might say that you will *compress* or *condense* the process, or *reduce* the processing time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the rare [instantaneize](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=BfJfVoA7Ij0C&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=%22instantaneizing%22&source=bl&ots=QSHPvl0Ng1&sig=PjrUKUGGHqN0d56iou3EoDOdTZA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=QWV9U5akL8eb0QWrmYHgAQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22instantaneizing%22&f=false).

> "The reaction takes 4 seconds to complete, but I bet we can *instantaneize* it."
>
> **instantaneize**: *(Gallicism) Fr.* [instantanéiser](http://www.universalis.fr/dictionnaire/instantaneiser/) : make instantaneous

Alternately, [constrict](http://t.answers.com/answers/?ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br%2F#!/entry/89e774a39b322a5f1b353aa3a347bb57&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.answers.com%2FQ%2FWhat_is_time_constriction%23page1&oswts=1400729315647) might fit what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

***[im·me·di·ate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/immediate)***  (ĭ-mē′dē-ĭt)

> *adj*. 1. Occurring at once; instant: *gave me an immediate response.*

I might like a slight rephrasing but anyway,

> The reaction takes 4 seconds to complete, but I bet we can make it **immediate**.

Think:

> The reaction takes 4 seconds to complete, but I bet we can make it an **immediate** reaction.

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense but this makes the most sense in the question.

Comment: You could then use the word "instant" instead of "immediate".

Answer (score 0):

'Synthesize' or 'amalgamate' could mean creating something by bringing a complex myriad of parts together to create something new. I'm not sure if this involves time. (Just a thought)

Comment: Second thought-- you could the word 'spontaneous' or 'immediate' with the word 'amalgamation'.

Answer (score -3):

[Abrupt](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abrupt).

Examples,

- The process completed abruptly.
- The process completion was abrupt.
- Instantiation of serialized objects like SOAP or REST objects are often prolonged by network latencies. However, the instantiation of primitive objects like an integer is abrupt.